# Azure OAuth2 flow when approval is requested

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, office365api

Our app implements Azure OAuth2 (v2) user-consent flow and uses Graph API scopes that do not require admin consent [oauth2 user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user). Recently we've noticed that some users of our app run into this Auth screen: "The app requires admin's approval".

[image: screenshot]

Is that because the tenant Org disabled user-consent for apps?

Where does it leave us with the user-consent based OAuth2 flow? Is it still possible to get a user access token after an admin's approval or the only way is to use the OAuth2 daemon flow [oauth2 daemon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service)? In a callback after such a dialog how can we know that the admin approval has been given?

One related question. In cases where user-consent is not disabled but it's an admin user that authorizes there is an option 'Consent on behalf of your Organization". How can we know in the callback from this dialog that the admin checked that box? And does it mean we need to use the OAuth2 daemon flow then too?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is that because the tenant Org disabled user-consent for apps?

Yes, this settings is under **Enterprise applications**->**User settings**.

[image]

> Is it still possible to get a user access token after an admin's
>   approval

Yes, you can still get a user access token after an admin's approval.

> In a callback after such a dialog how can we know that the admin
>   approval has been given?

Once your admin reviews the request you will be notified via email.

> In cases where user-consent is not disabled but it's an admin user
>   that authorizes there is an option 'Consent on behalf of your
>   Organization". How can we know in the callback from this dialog that
>   the admin checked that box?

Once the admin checked the box, the users under that tenant will not see the consent dialog. Also, you can check the status of the application in Azure portal->**App registrations**->your app->**API permissions**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It was our lack of understanding. After more testing we realized that we used prompt=consent and that is why the consent window always showed. Thank you.

Comment: By the way OAuth2 v2 docs don't describe the prompt= parameter. But I guess we kept using it from v1 days.

Comment: The `prompt` parameter is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#send-the-sign-in-request

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons  users  consent or adminconsent

For user consent two possible cases

1)In a tenant where user consent is disabled, for example, users can't consent to any permission. Azure AD-- > Enterprise apps ---> User settings ---> Users can consent to apps.

2) User assignment :Azure AD--- > Enterprise apps-- > (select app) --> Properties --> User assignment required

[image]

For [Admin Consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#using-the-admin-consent-endpoint) two possible cases

1) App-only permissions always require a tenant administrator’s consent. If your application requests an app-only permission and a user tries to sign in to the application, an error message is displayed saying the user isn’t able to consent.

2) Certain delegated permissions also require a tenant administrator’s consent. For example, the ability to write back to Azure AD as the signed in user requires a tenant administrator’s consent.

Solution :

1. The prompt=admin_consent parameter(which request permissions from admin) can be used as a parameter in the OAuth2/OpenID Connect authorization request to grant the admin consent .
2. Enable the admin consent workflow , which gives end users a way to request access to applications that require admin consent.
3. Refer the permissions documentation for the Microsoft Graph API indicate which permissions require admin consent.